# won't find specefic ID

Tags: php, jquery

I need to check if there is a `ID` found in the response with jQuery!
But it keeps giving me the alert `alert("else");`!

gastenboek.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkbox_warnings").on("change", function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $(this).attr("checked", false);
        } else {
            $("#warning_checkbox").slideUp(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });

    $("#gastenboek").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var url = "gastenboek_handler.php?action=check_gastenboek_form";
        var posting = $.post(url, form.serialize());

        posting.done(function(data) {

            if ($("#er-is-error").length) {
                var errors = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#gb-errors").slideDown().empty().append(errors);
                alert("if");
            } else {
                alert("else");
                $("#gb-errors").empty().slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Well there is an error but it doesn't `slideDown` the ID `#gb-errors`
I'm sure about this, because in the console it give a response with the error!

gastenboek_handler.php

```
<?php
include_once "/core/init.php";

if ($_GET['action'] == 'check_gastenboek_form')
{
    if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $_POST['email']))
    {
        $errors[] = "Dit is geen geldig e-mail adres!";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['msg']))
    {
        $errors[] = "Het berichten veld mag niet leeg zijn.";
    }
    else if (strlen($_POST['msg']) < 15)
    {
        $errors[] = "Het bericht mag niet minder dan 15 karakters hebben!";
    }
    else if (strlen($_POST['msg']) > 2500)
    {
        $errors[] = "Het bericht mag niet langer dan 2500 karakters hebben!";
    }

    if (!empty($errors))
    {
        foreach($errors as $error)
        {
            $return[] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" style="padding-right:5px; color:red;"></span><a class="errors" style="color:red;">' . $error . '</a><br>';
        }
        echo json_encode($return);
        echo '<div id="er-is-error"></div>';
    }
    else
    {
        gb_post($_POST);
    }
}
?>
```

hope you guys know something!

Comment: Does this element exist - `#gb-errors` in `DOM`?

Comment: `$("#gb-errors").slideDown('fast',function(){ $(this).empty().append(errors); });`

Comment: you are `echoing` - `'<div id="er-is-error"></div>'`.. Did you append it to `DOM`? since you are checking its length it has to be in `DOM`

Comment: an extra `}` `curly braces` !!

Comment: @freedomn-m where do you see a error then?

Comment: that was a mistake of me in this editor i updated it

Comment: in the code its not wrong

Comment: where are you echoing that div. on the same page where you are calling the js.

Comment: When are you running the js code?  Try putting it inside the jquery doc ready: `$(function() { if... })`.   Perhaps '#gb-errors' doesn't exist when the js runs, but does exist when you check it in the console after the page has loaded.

Comment: I updated it with the 2 files i USE

Comment: i think you need to do somrthing like this `if($(data).find("#er-is-error").length) { .. } else { .. }`

Comment: @AmitSoni Tried but not working as well!

Comment: the value you return from PHP does not look like valid or parseable html, since it always contains a Json object. try not to mix a json and html response, but instead use a json value to determine if there were server side errors.

Comment: @TimothyGroote oke thx ill try that

Comment: `if ($("#er-is-error", data).length)`  #er-is-error is in the post response (posting.done), *not* in the DOM.    You might need to parse data into HTML first as it's json+html mixed, but this might work - or just add it to your return[] first.